# Is it possible to access MongoDB's profile from the command line programatically?

Tags: php, bash, shell, mongodb

I want to create a monitoring script that sends me alerts about slow queries.

So I want to get the profile data programatically. I guess I could do it from PHP by connecting to MongoDB (not sure though).

But it would be better if I could access the profiler directly from a bash script. Is that possible?

Comment: I suppose if you were to build your own BSON decoder you could just look for the file that contains `db.system.profile` and process that, but really; this is easier in something like PHP and probably much better in terms of usage and interface. However most use a python or something agent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to running js files directly or connecting with a driver, you can also directly query mongodb from bash with curl / wget. All you need is to start your server with --rest

```
mongod --rest
```

If your server listens to 27017, then add 1000 to get the http port (in this case 28017). The page that you get is the admin page. You can do basic queries here like:

```
$ curl -i http://localhost:28017/<dbName>/<collectionName>/
```

i.e.

```
$ curl http://localhost:28001/test/foo/?filter_str=Hello   
{
  "offset" : 0,
  "rows": [
    { "_id" : { "$oid" : "50ab8a10df015a6dd00a44a7" }, "str" : "Hello" } ,
    { "_id" : { "$oid" : "50ab8a14df015a6dd00a44a8" }, "str" : "Hello", "x" : 1 }
  ],

  "total_rows" : 2 ,
  "query" : { "str" : "Hello" } ,
  "millis" : 0
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Mongo console provides a scripting mode which you could embed in a bash script. See the following page for details and usage:
[Scripting the MongoDB Shell](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Scripting+the+shell)

If you would like to use PHP and connect directly, PHP is on the list of MongoDB supported drivers and would give you a better interface then then scripted mongo. See the following for more info:
[MongoDB Drivers](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Drivers)

Comment: That only shows scripting with an external javascript file, I don't see any mention of bash

Comment: My suggestion was to execute the mongo console from within a bash script, passing Javascript code to execute. In the end I think you will be better served writing this in PHP using the Mongo PHP driver to interface.

Comment: Ah ok, it was a little confusing, it sounded like you could pass bash directly to mongo